# Local cluster installation .\DevClusterSetup.ps1 fails Waiting for Naming Service to be ready

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When trying to set up the local cluster the `powershell` script I get the following error:

[image: Screenshot of powershell responses]

Is there any way of continuing the installation or fixing the cause of this error?

Cheers,

Mike

---

I have completely removed the SDK and started over but I am still having the same issues. Everything boils down to the 'Connect-ServiceFabricCluster' just doesn't work at all (I have followed all of the suggestions provided).

Surely the warnings about the naming services must point to something?

Each attempt I see the following:

> WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
>   2>WARNING: Failed to connect Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM...
>   2>Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : A communication error caused the operation to fail.
>   2>At D:\Source\Play\ServiceFabricApplication\ServiceFabricApplication\Scripts\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1:158 char:16
>   2>+ ...      [void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @ClusterConnectionParameters ...
>   2>+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   2>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], FabricTransientException
>   2>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster

Attempting a reset from the tray:
[Tray output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFnpN.png)

Answer (score 2):

In my case the Cluster was not running (ie no `Fabric.exe` processes in Task Manager).

I was able to get things working again my opening a Powershell as Admin and running:

```
& "$ENV:ProgramFiles\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\DevClusterSetup.ps1"
```

After that **close** the powershell window and open a new one (as Admin).  Then `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` worked.

Answer (score 0):

This usually indicates that the main service host isn't running. If this is on our just-released public preview SDK, you can usually resolve these situations by resetting the cluster (just right click on the service fabric tray icon and click reset). If this is an older rev, well, then first you should upgrade :) But other than that you can check inside services.msc and make sure FabricHostSvc is running.

Comment: The services are not installed and there is no sign of the service fabric tray icon.

Comment: Ok, we added a link to the local cluster manager to Start in our latest SDK, and also improved local cluster setup. If you grab the latest SDK and try again we'd be glad to help you through this.

Answer (score 0):

The error is a temporary communication error. Open Task Manager, go to 'Details' tab and check if 'FabricHost.exe' and 'Fabric.exe' is running. This indicates if the cluster has been setup and running.

Open a new administrator PowerShell window and try to connect to cluster using '[Connect-ServiceFabricCluster](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125938.aspx)'.

If the connection still fails, try to remove the cluster using 'CleanCluster.ps1' and setup it again using 'DevClusterSetup.ps1'. This should fix the issue.

Please visit [Troubleshoot your local development cluster setup](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-troubleshoot-local-cluster-setup/).

Comment: No sign of any running service and the CleanCluster.ps1 script just hangs. It really does look like things go deeper than this.

The powershell shows "Removing cluster configuration ..." and doesn't get any further.

Comment: I have completely removed the SDK and started over but I am still having the same issues. Everything boils down to the 'Connect-ServiceFabricCluster' just doesn't work at all (I have followed all of the suggestions above).

Each attempt I see the following:

Comment: It seems like the cluster has gone into an inconsistent state. This will require looking at Service Fabric traces and figure out the actual cause. I am an engineer on the Service Fabric team. I can help you out if you can email me the Service Fabric traces (from logs folder) at harahma[at]microsoft[dot]com. 

If you are familiar with logging support tickets on Azure, I would suggest you do that too so we can track this issue to resolution. In the meantime I will continue to work on this to see how we can unblock you.

Comment: @mikehole Have you followed this problem to a solution? if so, please post it so others (like me) could use it to solve the same problem.

Comment: Sorry but I had to move on to other projects and have been looking at different micro services technology

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar situation where all the TCP connections were erroring out with a FabricTransientException exception.

The underlying cause turned out to be the Windows Firewall. Once I disabled the firewall for the domain network, the connections were successful and the services were again accessible.

P.S> In case someone faces the same issue: Initially the problem was that after the installation Fabric Host service was just stalling with the "Starting" status. Main cause for this problem was that Windows Firewall service was disabled on the server. After enabling and starting the windows service, the Fabric Host service started as expected.